# increase the effect of ambient occlusion

Tags: modeling, mesh

I use cycles to render. I set everything into ambient occlusion, but the shadows around the objects are a little bit too light, so I want to increase the effect of ambient occlusion, but I couldn’t find those features (on the attached image, which I found on here)on the world tab. I’m currently using blender 2.82 please help[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Is7G0.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure you are using Blender 2.82? Those don't look like images from that version. Are you sure you are using Cycles? The screenshot are showing the good old Blender Render (Internal). Could you clarify a bit your question, please?

Comment: The settings you are showing were for Blender Internal renderer, which has been discontinued after version 2.79. Are you using Eevee or Cycles in your project ?

Comment: Carlo-I found the image on here. It seems like the person who post it had the same question last year. I’m sorry for the confusion! I was trying to follow that tutorial, but I couldn’t find anything like that on blender version 2.82. Now that makes sense. I would like to know how to increase the effect of ambient occlusion with cycles (for2.82)

Comment: Gorgious-using cycles!